# Angular 2 - POST does not set Content-Type to application/json (its text/plain)

Tags: angular, http-post

I create a Contactformular, my simulated server is working, but in the Angular 2, there is my Create-function:

```
createPatient(Name: string, Nachname: string, Geburtsdatum: string, Strasse: string, Hausnummer: string, Postleitzahl: string, Wohnort: string): Observable<boolean> {
  let patient = {
      Id: 0,
      Name: Name,
      Nachname: Nachname,
      Geburtsdatum: Geburtsdatum,
      Strasse: Strasse,
      Hausnummer: Hausnummer,
      Postleitzahl: Postleitzahl,
      Wohnort: Wohnort
  };
  let body = JSON.stringify(patient);
  let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
  return this.http.post(this.patientenUrl + "CreatePatient", body, options)
    .map((r: Response) => {
        console.log(r);
        return <boolean>r.json();
    });
```

The body are not involvd in the Url, so my "server" does not work. Where do I fail?

i always get:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:9177/api/v1/CreatePatient
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9177/api/v1/CreatePatient. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 415
EXCEPTION: Response with status: 0 for URL: null
Uncaught Response with status: 0 for URL: null
```

After some help i get this solution:

```
createPatient(Name: string, Nachname: string, Geburtsdatum: string, Strasse: string, Hausnummer: string, Postleitzahl: string, Wohnort: string): Observable {
      let patient = {
          Id: 0,
          Name: Name,
          Nachname: Nachname,
          Geburtsdatum: Geburtsdatum,
          Strasse: Strasse,
          Hausnummer: Hausnummer,
          Postleitzahl: Postleitzahl,
          Wohnort: Wohnort
      };
      let body = JSON.stringify(patient);
      let headers = new Headers({ 'content-type': 'application/json', 'accept': 'application/json'});
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
      return this.http.post(this.patientenUrl + "CreatePatient", body, headers)
        .map((r: Response) => {
            console.log(r);
            return r.json();
        });
```

and now i get my body, but the Content-Type is 'text/plain'
so now i always get:

```
POST http://localhost:9117/api/v1/CreatePatient 415 (Unsupported Media Type)
EXCEPTION: Response with status: 415 Unsupported Media Type for URL: http://localhost:9117/api/v1/CreatePatient
Uncaught Response with status: 415 Unsupported Media Type for URL: http://localhost:9117/api/v1/CreatePatient
```

My Controller-function for Create:

```
    [Route("[action]")]
            [HttpPost]   
    public JsonResult CreatePatient([FromBody]Patient patient)
                {
                    this.ResStatus.Status = false;
                    var pat = patient;
                    var ida = GetId();
                    //Prüfung ob Customer Leer oder Null
                        pat.Id = (int)ida;
                        patientRepository.Insert(pat);
                        this.ResStatus.Status = true;
                        return Json(this.ResStatus.Status);                
                }
```

I solve the Problem:
i change the wwwroot from the ASP.NET Core into the Angular 2 Project and include the link from index.html that i can refresh without Problems.

Comment: what do you mean body not involved int the URL ? The body is the HTTP request body. Check it with your browser devtool. The problem might be in your server.

Comment: i check the server, but there is everything okey, my body do not exist in the return, i mean if i send the post_request i debug in google chrome and there i do not have the body.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you JSON.stringify your 'body'? You don't have to do that, it should work without JSON.stringify()

--

And by that I mean that you should either just send 'patient' or do a "body = patient;" and then send body.

Comment: Did you use the development tools in your browser to see that a request actually is sent?

Do you see in the REST-service that your request triggers a POST-request-handling?

Comment: to 1. Question: yes, we see that the request is build up and it is sended

Comment: but we see that he made a break with the error code 415 Unsupported Media type

Comment: Do you use Spring? It seems to me that your controller doesn't accept the mediatype you're sending. What does the @RequestMapping say on the method?

Comment: i test my create function, and it works fine, but the post in angular do not send an application/json, it send an text/plain

Comment: make the call like this, removing the headers:

return this.http.post(this.patientenUrl + "CreatePatient", patient)
        .map((r: Response) => {
            console.log(r);
            return r.json();
        });

What happens then?

Comment: with that i lose the patient (body) again

Comment: But you got application/json?

Comment: and in the javacode you have something like public void savePatient(@RequestBody Patient patient) ?

Comment: i have :  public JsonResult CreatePatient([FromBody]Patient patient){...}

Comment: You have [HttpPost] above the CreatePatient-method?

Comment: i include my C# Create function above

Comment: And you do not have [HttpPost] above the method?

Comment: sry, i have it i refresh it, one moment.

Comment: it do not work, i still not hit the controllerfunction

Comment: You get error 415 still? (Unsupported media type) ?

Comment: The problem is not angular 2 if angular 2 sends 'application/json' in the headers.

The problem is then the server which do not understand that the 'body' it's supposed to map to an object is JSON.

I think you have to make sure that your web-server understands that it's getting a JSON in the body and then knows how to map it to a "Patient"-object.

I'm sorry I can't help you anymore, I do not know that much C# / WebAPI as I mostly work with Java/Spring +Angular

Answer (score 0):

```
addBookWithObservable(book:Book): Observable<Book> {
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this.http.post(this.url, book, options)
           .map(this.extractData)
           .catch(this.handleErrorObservable);
```

https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-http-post-example

Comment: otherwise please install cors